# Message queue: msgsnd failed : Invalid argument : permission denied

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

i Two programs that communicate through a message queue.
Each time I can not send a message from a client program to a server program and I get an error message:
Invalid argument or permission denied

clint:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#define MAX_LEN 30

struct msgbuf
{
    long mtype; 
    char mtext[MAX_LEN];
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    struct msgbuf message;
    key_t key;
    int msgid;
    if((key = ftok("/tmp", 'e') == -1))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ftok() failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((msgid = msgget(key,0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("msgget failure");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }
    message.mtype = 0;
    fgets(message.mtext, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    if((msgsnd(msgid, &message, strlen(message.mtext) + 1, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("msgsnd failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((msgrcv(msgid, &message, MAX_LEN,0, MSG_NOERROR)) == -1)
    {
        perror("msgrcv failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%s", message.mtext);
}
```

server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define MAX_LEN 60
char* encode(char* string, char* encd_str);

struct msgbuf{
    long mytype; 
    char mtext[MAX_LEN];
};

int main()
{

    struct msgbuf message; // the file is steel decodded.
    key_t key;
    int msgid;
    long type = 0;
    char  encd_str[120];


    if((key = ftok("/tmp", 'e')) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ftok() failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((msgid = msgget(key,IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL |0600)) == -1)
    {
        perror("msgget failure");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if((msgrcv(msgid, &message, MAX_LEN,type, MSG_NOERROR)) == -1)
        {
            perror("msgrcv failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        encode(message.mtext, encd_str);

        if((msgsnd(msgid, &message, strlen(message.mtext) , 0)) == -1)
        {
            perror("msgsnd failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }

}

char* encode(char* string, char* encd_str)
{
    int i;
    int len = strlen(string);
    for(i =0; i < len; i++)
    {
        encd_str[i*2] = string[i];
        encd_str[i*2 + 1] = 'b';
    }
    encd_str[i*2 +  2]  = '\0';
    return encd_str;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you receive, and what program do you receive it from?

Comment: At least 1 typo: `if((key = ftok("/tmp", 'e') == -1))` should be `if((key = ftok("/tmp", 'e')) == -1)`

Comment: Also, `message.mtype` in the client should be greater than `0`. With `message.mtype = 1;` and the fix from my previous comment, your program works for me.